# How can I know when installation is finished?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

If I want to install msi on remote computer in quiet mode, an receive a confirmation if the installation completed successfully or did not succeeded.

I have tried to look for a solution in windows installer API but with no luck...
Is there an event or something like that?

Comment: How are you starting it on the remote machine?  psexec,  winrm, powershell?

Comment: Probably it will be powershell or psexec

Comment: msiexec will wait and return an exit code.

Comment: You mean "return value 3" in the log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found 3 options to validate installation.

1. From the installation log. Need to find "return value 3" - Error value.
2. The msiexec process will return exit code.
3. Using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Dll.